# What are limitations of side-by-side COM?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, com, clickonce, side-by-side

We need to adapt our application to be usable through ClickOnce. The application consists of a .exe file, and a huge set of Visual C++ libraries, some of them are in-proc COM servers used by other libraries.

Currently our installer does `regsvr32` to register the COM servers, but looks like ClickOnce applications are not allowed to modify the registry during installation. So we need something else.

Option one is to remove `CoCreateInstance()` and instead use `LoadLibraryEx()`/`DllGetClassObject()`. This will require code modification, but is very reliable - I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work.

Option two is to use side-by-side COM activation with manifests. The problem I see immediately is that we increment the version number in each nightly build, so we will have to update manifests automatically. That's not very inspiring. What are other not so obvious limitations of using side-by-side COM activation?

Comment: Why would you have to update the manifests? The critical thing in the manifest is the CLSID to dll mapping, there are some assembly version numbers to consider but they are not cross checked against the dlls embedded version numbers so the manifests, once set up, can lag quite a lot.

Comment: @Chris Becke: Really? I always expected that versions are checked thoroughly so that DLL hell is avoided.

Comment: What matters is the version number in the .manifest file, not the version info in the DLL. You can keep all the .manifest version numbers set to 1.0.0.0, if it makes it easier.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question.  You need reg-free COM, not winsxs.  Version numbers don't matter.  Nor has it any limitations.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Both use manifests. Okay. Where is the thin line separating SxS from reg-free COM? Isn't is just the same mechanism?

Comment: Reg-free COM makes up for missing registry entries, SxS alters the search path for DLLs.  Reg-free COM requires `<file>` and `<comClass>` or `<clrClass>`.

Comment: Once reg-free COM has located a COM server, you'll probably want to use SxS to locate the DLL. The COM and SxS config typically live next to each other in the same manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of side-by-side COM is that it solves your problem without any code changes -- it's possible to retrofit side-by-side COM to a set of existing COM components.

The downsides:

- Side-by-side is not a widely-used technique (outside a couple of components such as the VC++ runtime library and Windows Common Controls, which don't use COM), and it takes some effort to find troubleshooting information on the web
- If you're on XP or Server 2003 then you get no help from the OS when things go wrong. In particular, XP gives misleading messages in the event log; 2k3 is better. Vista and above give you the *sxstrace* tool.
- You'll need to maintain manifest files in parallel with the components themselves. In many respects, the manifest files duplicate information already in type libraries. Whereas you can maintain these by hand (they're XML files with a reasonably simple schema), you might want to re-generate them each time you do a build. This takes care of the versioning problem.

Comment: That's not it.  The OP started it off wrong, he's talking about reg-free COM, not winsxs.

Comment: They use the same mechanisms - reg-free COM is a subset of WinSxS

Comment: It's not.  They both use a manifest, that's where the similarities end.

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing. Can you post some links to WinSxS and reg-free COM documentation?

Comment: Good summary articles on MSDN: [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973915.aspx) and [COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)